# I get an error in MaterialBetterSpinner

Tags: android, listview, better-listview

```
>  android {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.pp.receipe"
                minSdkVersion 15
                targetSdkVersion 25
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })

            compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        }

Here is my code and android monitor debug error
```

[image]

Comment: kindly post your xml `activity_welcome`

Comment: <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Select Language"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library need exclude appcompat check the [README](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner) of BetterSpinner

your dependency should look like this in your gradle

```
compile ('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.BetterSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Select Language"/>
```

I CHANGE  .BetterSpinner INSTEAD OF MATERIAL BETTER SPINNER